# Solution of Exact and Homogeneous differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the equation
$(5y - 2x) (\dfrac{dy}{dx}) - 2y = 0$
This equation is Exact and Homgeneous differential equation. When i use the exact method then i get the following solution
$2xy -(5/2) y^2 = c$
And when I use the Homogeneous method of solution that is putting $y = vx$ in Homogeneous differential equation then I get the following solution
$ln (y) + \dfrac{2x}{5y} = c$.
Question is that are both right solutions. Im confused about different solution. Explain it please.

Comment: If you substitute each back into the ODE, do they both work?

Comment: Actually i just recheck my solution and i found that i did wrong cancellation in the solution. So after correction i got the right answer that is 2xy - (5/2) y^2 = c . And thank you for reminding me that i can verify the solution by plugging it in the given differential equation. Thank you

Comment: @Isham: Looks like by checking, s/he found his issues.

Comment: Oh I see now @mpp

Answer (score 2):

$$(5y - 2x) (\dfrac{dy}{dx}) - 2y = 0$$
$$ y' =\frac {2y}{(5y - 2x)}$$
Since the equation is homogenous then substitute $y=tx$
$$ t'x+t =\frac {2t}{(5t - 2)}$$
$$ t'x =\frac {4t-5t^2}{(5t - 2)}$$
$$ \int \frac{(5t - 2)} {4t-5t^2}dt=\ln|x|+K$$
$$ -\frac 12\int \frac 1tdt+\frac 52\int \frac{ dt} {4-5t}=\ln|x|+K$$
$$ -\frac 12\ln|t|-\frac 12\int \frac{ dt} {t-4/5}=\ln|x|+K$$
$$ -\frac 12\ln|t|-\frac 12\ln|t-4/5|=\ln|x|+K$$
$$ \ln|y|+\ln|\frac yx-4/5|+\ln|x|=K$$
$$ xy(\frac yx-\frac 45)=K$$
Exactly what you had with exact differential method
$$\boxed{ y^2-\frac {4}5xy=K}$$

Comment: Ohhhh thanks . . Thumbs up 